# How can I pass information from a database in Wordpress to Javascript on the front end?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress

I am using Wordpress, php, mysql and Javascript

In wordpress I have a database called "my_database".

I want to pass information from my_database to javascript front end. So i can manipulate the data and display it.

my_database  ->    Javascript

What ways Should i Do this?

At the moment my current approach would be to use

```
$result = $wpdb -> get_results();
```

then use

```
wp_localize_script($result, "javascriptVariable");
```

Is there an easier way or is this the recommended way?

Any help and guidance is appreciated

Comment: `wp_localize_script` is useful to set global variables inside JavaScript, e.g. a specific endpoint to be called from JS. What are you trying to pass to the frontend? probably an API call could be your best deal, instead of `wp_localize_script`

Comment: Trying to pass a dictionary.

Comment: looking at [the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) you should provide your registered script name as first parameter, then the JS variable name as second parameter, and the result of your query as the third paramter. something like
`wp_localize_script('script_name','dictionary', $result)`

Comment: Would the "wordpress way" be to call the wp api?

Comment: You have two ways, pass the data using wp_localize_script() or create REST endpoints for data manipulation.